# Problems on pushing my project to Github

Tags: git, github

I am new on GitHub, trying to push one of my projects to it.
This is what I did (I have done with SSH and `git config --global` such things)

```sh
# cd to my project dir
git init
# Created a readme.txt
git add readme.txt
git add .
git remote add origin <address of repository>
git push origin master
```

then it shows me error

```
failed to push some refs to <my repositories address>
```

Then, nothing changed on my respositories which Ive tried to push my project to.

Comment: Please post the output of `git status` and `git log -1 --decorate --oneline`

Comment: Thx.. Problem already solved right now

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `git commit` to commit your files.

Comment: After git add . or after git remote ?

Comment: That means you have committed. Try pushing again?

Comment: You will have to do a `git pull` before you `git push` again.

Comment: Can you post message you see in your terminal when you type `git status` ?

Comment: It gave me this after git status......................................# On branch master                                                              nothing to commit, working directory clean